# How to parse over different elements in a HTML document (in Dart/Flutter) and keep the order intact

Tags: html, dart, parsing

- I have a large HTML document containing important information of different types in sequence.
- I'm parsing in Dart/Flutter
- Obtaining the raw information is fine
- My problem is that parsing for Elements of the different types/names (Image, text, headings etc) will lose the order in which the elements are displayed in relation to each other in the document.

Eg. A heading, then an image, then some text, then another image, then some text.

I really need the equivalent to this: html.getElementsByTagName('title' or 'p' or 'whatever-else-I-need'). Then I can process in the loop and output my model in a properly sequenced list.

Parsing sequence-critical information of different element tags / data types must be a common occurrence. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how you're losing order?  Are you attempting to do ad hoc parsing yourself instead of using, say, [`package:html`](https://pub.dev/packages/html)?

Comment: I'm using package:html/parser.dart. To pull the information out of tags I'm using var whatever = html.parse(input).getElementbyTagName or .getElementById. I need individual data I'm passing into my own model.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on `package:html` (nor with HTML and CSS in general), but I think that you can use [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://pub.dev/documentation/html/latest/dom/Document/querySelectorAll.html) with an appropriate selector string:

```dart
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as html;

void main() {
  var htmlStr = r'''
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<img src="foo.png">
</body>
</html>  
''';
  var document = html.parse(htmlStr);
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('title,p,img');
  elements.forEach(print);
  // Prints: 
  // <html title>
  // <html p>
  // <html img>
}
```

If a selector doesn't do what you want, you could write a function that walks the tree:

```dart
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

/// Walks [document] and invokes [elementCallback] on each element using a preorder
/// traversal.
///
/// [elementCallback] should return true to continue walking the tree, false to
/// abort.
void walk(dom.Document document, bool Function(dom.Element) elementCallback) {
  var stack = <dom.Element>[];
  stack.addAll(document.children.reversed);
  while (stack.isNotEmpty) {
    var element = stack.removeLast();
    if (!elementCallback(element)) {
      break;
    }
    stack.addAll(element.children.reversed);
  }
}
```

and then you could run `walk` with an appropriate callback that conditionally adds each `Element` to some `List`, e.g.:

```dart
var elements = <dom.Element>[];
var wantedTags = {'title', 'p', 'img'};
walk(document, (element) {
  if (wantedTags.contains(element.localName)) {
    elements.add(element);
  }
  return true;
});
```